# c# webBrowser does not work with Iframes

Tags: c#, iframe, webbrowser-control

I have a webBrowser in my application with a status bar that shows link addresses when

mouse over whit this code:

```
lbl1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href");
```

but it does not work in iframes. What I must do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that. I must to change this:

```
lbl1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href");
```

to this edited line:

```
lbl1.Text = (sender as HtmlDocument).GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href")
```

and this is complete code block:

```
    void Document_MouseOver(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
      lbl1.Text = (sender as HtmlDocument).GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href");
    }
```

and after that add this block code where you want to apply to WebBrowser

```
        string html = string.Empty;

        foreach (HtmlWindow frame in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames)
        {

            frame.Document.MouseUp+=new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseUp);

            frame.Document.MouseOver+=new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseOver);

        }

    }
```

to adding events for all frames in the page.